# Can I backup user data according to Google Drive API Terms of Service?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

ToS states - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/terms:

"The Drive API is not allowed for certain use cases without Google’s express prior written consent, including the following:

- Backup of user/app content from developer’s app to Drive."

While on Introduction to Google Drive API we read - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk:

"You can use Google Drive API to:

- Create a dedicated Drive folder to store your application’s data so that the app cannot access all the user's content stored in Google Drive. See Store application-specific data."

So can I use it to store user data, which it generates while using the app and autosync it like Viber does? It could be `.json` files, maybe photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [application data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) folder is a special hidden folder that your app can use to store application-specific data, such as configuration files. The application data folder is automatically created when you attempt to create a file in it. Use this folder to store any files that the user shouldn't directly interact with. This folder is only accessible by your application and its contents are hidden from the user and from other Drive apps.

There's a big difference between `user/app content from developer’s app` and `configuration file`.

Comment: So if I understood right, I won't violate the Terms if I would create that hidden `application data folder`, and would store and sync any needed data in it? Not only configuration, but media files, specific data (notes for example) stored in text format?

Comment: ah, sorry, I think I got it. I can store **application**, not **user** specific data, so I can't store something like user's notes, right? I wonder why is that, if only user and app will be seeing it? And how do I get that "Google’s express prior written consent"? I wrote to Google Drive support and they could not help or redirect my question in any way. There are no Drive API support, etc.

Comment: All of this is a very gray line and open for interpretation.  When you go through the verification process if your doing anything wrong im sure google will let you know.

Comment: @DalmTo I think Firestore is what Google would like us to use in this situation. Another solution is just manual exporting. Thank you for your answer!